# Changeable return data type in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing a matrix class, and I want it to be able to store any different (numerical) data type - from boolean to long.

In order to access the data I'm using the brackets operator. Is it possible to make that function return different data types depending on which data type is stored within the class. What's MORE is that I'm not entirely sure how I would STORE different data types within the class under the same variable name. It may well not be possible.

The only way I can think to store the data as any type would be to store it as a void and store the type of data as an extra variable. however RETURNING as a void would cause problems, no? Because I would want to return as the data type I have stored in the function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read up on templates.

Answer (score 10):

Your answer is templates!

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
    T* data;
public:
    // ....
    T& operator()( size_t x, size_t y )
    {
        return data[ y*MAXX + x ]; 
    }

}
```

You can read about templates [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_c++/Chapter16.html).

Comment: Thanks. Just a note with your code, is it a typo in your code that you've used the square bracket operator? I don't know if I specified in my post that I was using round brackets (). however I only chose to use them because it appeared that the square bracket operator was only allowed to take a single argument.

Is this a mistake on my part?

Comment: Yeah, my bad, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 2):

If all elements of the matrix will be the same type as each other (ie it's a homogenous matrix - so all ints or all floats, etc) then the templated approach is the right way.

If, however, you want to be able to store heterogenous types (ie some ints, some floats, etc) then you'll have to use some sort of variant type. A good example is boost's [`variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/variant.html) implementation.

You could also just use a `union`, but you'll probably end up writing much of the infrastructure of `variant` anyway.